# Find alphanumeric strings from ArraList using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, regex, stream

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ABC","123ABC","def","def45","2GHI","u3ht",
              "zxy","t12pp", "kkk");
```

Note: print only alphanumeric strings - 123ABC, def457, 2GHI, u3ht, tt12pp

I tried as below but not working.

```
List<String> alphanNist = list.stream() 
      .filter(s->s.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Do you expect your regex to not match the string "ABC"? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class SO72918446 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{2,}$");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ABC","123ABC","def","def45","2GHI","u3ht","zxy","t12pp", "kkk");
        List<String> alphanNist = list.stream().filter(s->pattern.matcher(s).matches()).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
        System.out.println(alphanNist);
    }
}
```

prints

In case you are wondering what the pattern means , you can refer
regexr.com/6pdb2

```
[123ABC, def45, 2GHI, u3ht, t12pp]
```

However as comment says , if you want to match ABC as well, the Regex has to be modified a bit [(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*] would work there!

Comment: As the reason for the OPs question is that they don't understand regexes, this answer needs a detailed explanation of what the regex shown does, and why it works when the OPs does not.

Comment: I think the below code too work out right?
List<String> alphanNist = list.stream().filter(s->s.matches("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{2,}$")).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
        System.out.println(alphanNist);